# How can I implement the naïve Bayes algorithm?

Tags: python, naivebayes

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

cigdata = pd.read_csv ('cigs.csv')
print(cigdata.head())
cigdata.shape
#Changing pandas dataframe to numpy array
X = cigdata.iloc[:,:8].values
y = cigdata.iloc[:,8:9].values
#Normalizing the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X = sc.fit_transform(X)
```

I am trying to normalize my data for implementation of naïve Bayes algorithm but it is not working as I have string values in my dataset and it's showing something like this:

> valuetype error string value cannot be converted to float.

Comment: Ok, so the problem seems to be, you are reading some data from a CSV which however is interpreted by python as string (probably because it is wrapped by "" in the csv. Could you however provide more concrete error messages? "its showing something like this valuetype error string value cannot be converted to float" is not very useful for narrowing down the possible cause of an error.

Comment: X = sc.fit_transform(X) on this line its giving me error sir as i have some columns in my dataset which contain some string values so its giving me error that string value cannot be converted to float and naming it as valuetype error

Comment: Could you also provide the `cigs.csv` If its large, at least a sample of it.

Comment: Alpine   Lt     15        1.1 16 100 F SP                  yes

Comment: these above  values are of the 1st row and it contain total 9 columns

Comment: Sir can you  give me your email address i would be able to share file with you and you can check error easily

Comment: So in your csv, you have some data, But as you can see the first, second and 7-9th columns are not numeric, they are a string of text. This is what `StandardScaler` is complaining about. You have to convert them into a numeric value (for example yes=1, no=0 etc..) Check https://pbpython.com/categorical-encoding.html

Comment: this conversion process is very lengthy sir is their any other way i mean any function which can be use for string values?

Comment: There is an answer provided for converting string categories to numbers bellow. If you have specific issues related to that answer, please discuss it in the comments here. If you are facing a different issue, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LabelEncoder` from `sklearn`

In your case, the categorical columns are index `[0, 1, 6, 7, 8]`
You can Encode them using this code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 

# ....

cat_index = [0, 1, 6, 7, 8]
cigdata.iloc[:, cat_index] = cigdata.iloc[:, cat_index].apply(LabelEncoder().fit_transform)
```

Place this after the `read_csv` and you should be left with a data frame containing only numerical values.